# Azure Synapse - Move SQLPool to another workspace

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

I need to redeploy my synapse workspace, but want to keep all dedicated sqlPools.

How can the sqlPools getting moved to a different synapse workspace like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Restore point** can be one of the ways to achieve your requirement. But in this method, you need to create new pool in another synapse workspace and **delete or pass the old one in old workspace**.

This is my sample table in the dedicated pool of old synapse workspace.

[image]

First Go to your **Dedicated SQL pool and create a restore point for it**.

[image]

We need to use this restore point while creating new dedicated pool in the target synapse workspace.

First Give your new dedicated pool name and in **Additional settings** use the restore point and create it.

[image]

You can see we got the data from that pool here(I have not inserted any data in it).

[image]

But, if you want to move lot of pools, this method involves lot of manual work.